# TFS 2015 cannot implement work item security - TF212017: Work item tracking schema validation warning

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to implement security on a work item level

Definition xml

```
<TRANSITION from="new" to="in progress" not="[DefaultCollection]\DevOps">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Changing release" />
  </REASONS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Importing through command

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:collection_url/p:project /f:filepath\Bug.xml
```

Error is

> TF212017: Work item tracking schema validation warning: TF26171:
>   User/group '[DefaultCollection]\DevOps' is not found.

The group definitely exists because I can write a work item query with

> "AssignedTo = '[DefaultCollection]\DevOps'

and I get some results.

The group exists but it not recognised on witadmin import. Also the group is an existing group so should be synced. However I have tried to force a sync by ...

1. Restarting IIS
2. Rebuilding the client cache (witadmin rebuildcache /collection:collection_url)
3. Restarting the TFS job service on the TFS app server

I've also tried these combinations

1. New tfs projects and existing tfs projects
2. security groups on project level and team project level

I still get the same error. I'm on TFS 2015 Update 4

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS supports the following group definitions:

1. "[Project]\Project Group" - for local projects
2. "[Global]\Collection Group" - for collections (maybe this is your case)
3. "Domain\Domain Group" - for domains

Additional links:

1. [Apply or ignore rules based on user or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2019#apply-or-ignore-rules-based-on-user-or-group)
2. [Trying to customize the "Assigned To" field](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb90012f-ea1f-411e-9909-e7b4edd7b527/trying-to-customize-the-assigned-to-field?forum=tfsgeneral)

Comment: Excellent - thank you for this. The problem was that I thought [Project] was a placeholder for the project name but it isn't. It is a keyword. As you say it is [Project] when the group is at the project level and [Global] if it is at the Team Project Collection level